# Robocopy: echo nothing when logging file

Tags: robocopy

I am using **Robocopy** to write to log files:

`robocopy "C:\source" "E:\destination" /e /l /njs /njh /log:C:\folder1\reconcile1.txt`

When I use this in my batch file the console shows:  `Log File : C:\folder1\reconsile1.txt`

I do no want anything `echoed` from this command.  Is there a way to keep this away from appearing on the console?

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect all output to nul:

```
robocopy "C:\source" "E:\destination" /e /l /njs /njh /log:C:\folder1\reconcile1.txt > nul
```